# What does "rate 10000 cir 0" mean on an alcatel device?

Tags: speed, alcatel-lucent-7750

What does "rate 10000 cir 0" mean on an alcatel device?

- I thought cir ment "committed information rate" but why would it be
  set on 0 in this example?
- What does the "rate 10000" stand for?

Comment: You really need to add some context to this question if you want to get an answer. For example what output statements shows this or show relevant configuration parts. Also, please be more specific in the what kind of Alcatel device you're using.

Comment: @TeunVink the tag literally mentions the 7750 product. Is this in a scheduler, policer or queue context?

Comment: it's always smart to put all relevant information in the actual question, not just in the tags.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User Teun Vink is very correct in his assertion that context is required, mainly in the platform that you are using and the configuration that the rate is being applied to, whether QoS or service utilization. Nevertheless, here is some basic information:

CIR is your committed rate, which is the desired bandwidth of a service. It is not an indication of maximum, but a reservation of minimum bandwidth on the available interfaces the services is built. In an Alcatel-Lucent service router, the CIR is measured in kbps. As an example, if you have a 10gbps port and your services' CIR is 1048576, then your service has reserved all 1gbps of the port. If you then also have 10gbps of services mapped through that port without a CIR, then the service at 1gbps will always have 1gbps available to it, while all of the other traffic will be buffered and delayed in favor of that traffic. Most boxes will not allow you to provision a CIR that is higher than the maximum bandwidth capacity of a given port, though.

Assuming that you are using an Alcatel-Lucent service router in the 7xxx range of products, then the rate is a measurement of maximum kbps. The individual who applied "rate 10000" was probably trying to map the service for 10mbps, not realizing that our world of telecommunications and computing exists in base 16. The true measurement of 10mbps would be 10240kbps.

Comment: Good point. There are definitely differences between platforms, being that the 7xxx series from Alcatel-Lucent is base 10, and the 1850 line from the same manufacturer operates in base 16. Regarding port speeds, however, anything gig-e or higher should not be autonegotiating, even if the capability exists on that individual platform. There are too many platforms, even today, that don't accommodate autonegotiation on those higher rate ports. Also, oversubscription is typically handled with PIR, rather than CIR, because of that.

Answer (score 1):

that could be to create a congestion scenario to kick off QoS

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your answer by editing it to add more details to make it more useful both for the original poster and future users. Typically short answers like this could provide reasoning why you believe this is the answer, more explanation about the concepts mentioned, references/links to supporting resources, or applicable examples.